# Cascade Kingdom floating island Power Moon

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In the Cascade Kingdom - Fossil Falls section of Super Mario Odyssey there is a floating island directly above the Top of the Big Stump waypoint.

How do I get the Power Moon located on that floating island?
[image: floating island]

Comment: That "Y" button prompt looks pretty interesting... does it let you fly around?

Comment: @musefan when playing two player the Y button let's the second player (who's playing as Cappy) fly around Mario.  It's not complete free flight.

Comment: Friend has the same problem. I watched this whole video but the closest one is [this one on the floating islands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQoJ2-LpvwQ&t=401s) but it looks different than your screenshot...

Comment: I’m guessing you need to pass through a portrait to get up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the painting. The one in the snow kingdom leads to the cascade kingdom. I think the issue lies in the fork in the road when you finish the metro kingdom. You can go to the seaside or the snow kingdom. If you go to seaside first, the painting takes you to cascade and the snow one takes you to the lake kingdom. If you go to the snow kingdom first, it is the opposite. I went to snow first, so that's why it takes me to cascade and the seaside painting takes me to lake. This should solve the disparities. The painting in the snow kingdom is behind a tall wooden block near the odyssey that you can blow away with the cloud enemy near the odyssey. I would show a picture but it won't upload, so I hope this helps

Comment: This is a great answer.  This could be improved upon if you spaced out some paragraphs.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/2017/10/27/16542854/cascade-kingdom-power-moon-locations-find):

> To get this power moon, you need to travel to Seaside Kingdom. After you beat the boss there, swim and climb up to any of the water spouts. They’ll fling you to where the boss used to be. Swim down from where you land, and you’ll find a painting. That will warp you to an island overlooking Cascade Kingdom. There, you’ll find a flag and a power moon.

I've definitely not made it to Seaside Kingdom yet myself, but their screenshots seem like that's definitely the one.

[image: power moon]

Comment: Haven’t reached that point yet either, can anyone else confirm?

Comment: I went to the seaside kingdom, the painting there takes you to the lake kingdom not the cascade kingdom. I'm still not sure which painting takes you to cascade but all the guides say it's the seaside one, which is wrong. I'll edit the post if I find the right painting

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson. I retract my previous comment. The Seaside Kingdom's painting links to the Steam Gardens, not Fossile Falls. Still, to reach this Power Moon, you need to find a painting in one of the later kingdoms.

Comment: The Prima guide book implies that the locations that the paintings link to vary based on what choices you make at the forks in the road. I am not 100% clear on the connection though

Comment: @Margaret It seems that rather than take you to a specific Kingdom it takes you to a Kingdom exactly X steps before/after the current one along the Odyssey’s route. Because of this the choices at each fork affects the paintings; to wit, whichever is first of Seaside and Snow is exactly 8 Kingdoms before the Odyssey, plus Dark and Darker when those are unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

The warp painting that leads to the moon is actually in two different kingdoms, depending on which you chose first. The one in the seaside kingdom is in the sparkle water fountain right at the bottom, and the one in the snow kingdom, if you picked seaside first, after you exit the odyssey, capture the first tyfoo you see and then go northeast to a wooden platform to blow hard twice, then a small cap jump up to the painting